# clickable text in webapp no functioning

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I have a simple and basic code for a Tizen web . when text is clicked, it is supposed to launch the messaging app on my watch, however currently clicking the text does not do anything.

Could someone please advise why my code is not working? what am I missing??

This is my index.html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/main.js"></script> 

    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="page" >    
    <p id="para">Launch Messaging</p> 
      </div>

      </body>
     </html>
```

This is my main.js

```
    (function() {

    function launchApp() 
    {tizen.application.launch("com.samsung.message");}

    function init() {
    window.getElementById('page').addEventListener('click', launchApp);
       }

    // Launch messaging app
    window.onload = init();

     }());
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use "Hello Tizen" web sample application.

and, use this code to launch message apps.

```
    // Add click event listener
    textbox.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // Removed original code to toggle text.
        tizen.application.launch("org.tizen.w-message");
    });
```

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. This code is for a widget i'm developing for my Gear Sport Watch. would the code recommended by @lunchbasket work in a widget? it does not seem to be working for me?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problems is not clear to me, but I can suggest you some things which could help to find the perfect solution.

First of all, I would suggest to use callbacks in application as:

> tizen.application.launch("com.samsung.message", () => console.log("successfully launched"), (e) => console.log(e));

which will show you an message in case of problems and the confirmation in case of success. I consider adding success/error callbacks as a good practice.

Additionally I noticed that Galaxy Watch has a problem with starting "com.samsung.message" application, when it is not properly paired with mobile (application is disabled then and running it is not possible). When I paired them, application is launched properly.

Moreover, let me share different feature - application control. You can start application using implicit launch, which triggers default operation for some operation [e.g. http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/share_text](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/application-management/application-controls/common-application-controls?langredirect=1) which allows you to start dedicated applications for the action you need. Maybe this could help you to have your application more flexible for user-favourite-messsaging applications, without hardcode application id.

> var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl(
>       "http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/share_text");
>   tizen.application.launchAppControl(appControl, null, () => console.log("success"), (e) => console.log(e));

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. This code is for a widget i'm developing for my Gear Sport Watch. would the code recommended by @lunchbasket work in a widget? it does not seem to be working for me?

Comment: 15kokos code is more useful to you, because message app's id is not same on Gear and emulator.